# submit symfony 3 form with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, symfony, modal-dialog

I'm trying to implement my symfony forms / modal ,with ajax to stop reloading page every time time I submit an add/remove and update action, but the problem that I'm not familiar with ajax and I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me understand the concept.

mY entity :

```
<?php

namespace EvalBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Department
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="department")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EvalBundle\Repository\DepartmentRepository")
 */
class Department
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string",unique=true)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * One Department has Many Collaborators.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Collaborator", mappedBy="department")
     */
    private $collaborators;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Department
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

form :

```
<?php

namespace EvalBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class DepartmentType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'EvalBundle\Entity\Department',
            'attr' => array('novalidate' => 'novalidate')

        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'evalbundle_department';
    }


}
```

Controller :

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: sa7noun
 * Date: 5/15/17
 * Time: 12:09 PM
 */

namespace EvalBundle\Controller;

use EvalBundle\Entity\Department;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DepartmentController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Department entities.
     *
     * @Route("/department", name="department_index")
     * @Method({"GET","POST"} )
     *
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $department = new Department();
        $form = $this->createForm('EvalBundle\Form\DepartmentType', $department);
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($department);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('department_index');
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $departments = $em->getRepository('EvalBundle:Department')->findAll();
        /**
         * @var $paginator \Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator
         */
        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $result = $paginator->paginate(
            $departments,
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
            $request->query->getInt('limit', 5)
        );

        return $this->render('EvalBundle:Department:department.html.twig', array(
            'departments' => $result,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));

    }

//    /**
//     * Creates a new Department entity.
//     *
//     * @Route("/department/new", name="department_new")
//     * @Method({ "POST"})
//     */
//    public function newAction(Request $request)
//    {
//        $department = new Department();
//        $form = $this->createForm('EvalBundle\Form\DepartmentType', $department);
//        $form->handleRequest($request);
//
//        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
//            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
//            $em->persist($department);
//            $em->flush();
//
//            return $this->redirectToRoute('department_index');
//        }
//
//        return $this->render('EvalBundle:Department:department.html.twig', array(
//            'department' => $department,
//            'form' => $form->createView(),
//        ));
//    }


    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing department entity.
     *
     * @Route("department/{id}/edit", name="department_edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Department $department)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($department);
        $editForm = $this->createForm('EvalBundle\Form\DepartmentType', $department);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);


        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('department_edit', array('id' => $department->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('EvalBundle:Department:edit.html.twig', array(
            'department' => $department,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a department entity.
     *
     * @Route("department/{id}", name="department_delete")
     * @Method({"GET","DELETE"})
     */
    public function deleteAction(Department $department)
    {

//        $response = array(
//            'success' => true,
//            'message' => '',
//            'html' => '',
//        );
//
//          $form = $this->createDeleteForm($department);
//        if ($request->getMethod() == 'DELETE'){
//            $form->handleRequest($request);
//        }
//
        if ($department) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($department);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('department_index');
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a department entity.
     *
     * @param Department $department The department entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm(Department $department)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('department_delete', array('id' => $department->getId())))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->getForm();
    }

}
```

View (Index):

```
    {% extends 'default/superAdminBase.html.twig' %}
    {% block body %}

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #0089db">
                    <h5 style="text-align: center"><b>Départements</b></h5>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-fixed table-paginated">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {% for department in departments %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <b>{{ department.name }}</b>
                                        <a href="{{ path('department_edit', { 'id': department.id }) }}"
                                           class="btn btn-default btn-circle " style="float: right">
                                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="{{ path('department_delete', {'id': department.id}) }}"
                                           class="btn btn-danger btn-circle remove-item"
                                           data-entity-id="{{ department.id }}" style="float: right" data-toggle="modal">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="infos">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        Etes-vous sur de vouloir supprimer ce Département !
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <button href=" #" class="btn btn-info delete-item"
                                                                data-dismiss="modal">OUI
                                                        </button>
                                                        <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">NON</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.table-responsive -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel-body -->
            </div>
            <div class="navigation text-center">
                {{ knp_pagination_render(departments) }}
            </div>

            <!-- /.panel -->
            <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal-1" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            {% if app.session.flashBag.has('success') %}
                                <div class="aler alert-success">
                                    {% for msg in app.session.flashBag.get('success') %}
                                        {{ msg }}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}

                            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title"> Ajouter un nouveau département</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-input">
                            {{ form_start(form,{'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal','data-parsley-validate':''}}) }}
                            {{ form_widget(form.name,{'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Nom de département', 'data-parsley-required':'true', 'data-parsley-required-message':'le nom ne doit pas être vide :D'}}) }}
                            <br>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-offset-8 col-lg-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"><span
                                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Créer
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {{ form_end(form) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#myModal-1" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary "><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Ajouter un
            département</a>
        {% block javascript %}
            <script src="{{ asset('JS/departmentValidation.js') }}"></script>
        {% endblock %}
    {% endblo

ck %}
```

Answer (score 26):

i will answer this very basically to let you get an idea !

so first of all you will have to separate the saving part on the server side, because it will not return a view anymore like your indexAction does. Instead it returns some json data your ajax call on the client side can receive

your new controller action may look somelike this:

```
   /**
    * Creates a new Department entity.
    *
    * @Route("/department/new", name="department_new")
    * @Method({ "POST"})
    */
   public function newDepartmentAction(Request $request)
   {
        $department = new Department();
        $form = $this->createForm('EvalBundle\Form\DepartmentType', $department);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $status = "error";
        $message = "";

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($department);
            try {
                $em->flush();
                $status = "success";
                $message = "new department saved";
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $message = $e->getMessage();
            }    
        }else{
            $message = "invalid form data";
        }

        $response = array(
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $message
        );

        return new JsonResponse($response);

        // above is just an example of one way using formtypes, 
        // you can retrieve any parameter you send here like: 
        // $param = $request->get('param');


   }
```

you can do above whatever you want like paginate over all departments and return them, but you would need a js way to display the returned JSON then, you cant use twig for that because the view is already returned, you definetly want to use any datadriven JS View Model lib with automatic ui refresh.

Next, The client Side - From the client side you will have to send the the correct data to that action

so you have to serialize the formfields to a set of properties and values that you can send to the server. We will first serialize the form to a javascript object.

here you have a function for that that you have to include somewhere after jquery has loaded and before your further code

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

Next you have to avoid actually submitting the form non-ajax, because clicking on the submit button will lead to submit the form and reload the page, we prevent that behaviour, assuming the form has some unique selector eG. id="newDepartmentForm"

```
$(document).on("submit", "#newDepartmentForm", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return  false;
});
```

now lets assume you want to save by clicking on a button with specific id

```
$(document).on("click", "#mySubmitButton", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $("#newDepartmentForm");

  // you could make use of html5 form validation here
  if(!form[0].checkValidity()){

    // To show the native error hints you can fake a click() on the actual submit button
    // which must not be the button #mySubmitButton and shall be hidden with display:none;
    //  example:
    //  <button type="button" id="#mySubmitButton" class"btn btn-default" > Save </button>
    //  <button type="submit" id="#myHIDDENSubmitButton" style="display:none;"></button>
    //
    $("#myHIDDENSubmitButton").click();
    return false;
  }

  // get the serialized properties and values of the form 
  var form_data = form.serializeObject();

  // always makes sense to signal user that something is happening
  $('#loadingSpinner').show();

  // simple approach avoid submitting multiple times
  $('#mySubmitButton').attr("disabled",true);

  // the actual request to your newAction
  $.ajax({
    url: '/department/new',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: form_data,
    success:function(data){

      // handling the response data from the controller
      if(data.status == 'error'){
        console.log("[API] ERROR: "+data.message);
      }
      if(data.status == 'success'){
        console.log("[API] SUCCESS: "+data.message);
      }

      // signal to user the action is done
      $('#loadingSpinner').hide();
      $('#mySubmitButton').attr("disabled",false);
    }
  });
});
```

basically thats it.

if you want to make your site full Ajax-driven, you can request any data from the server like this, for example you may want to load all existing departments first you could just do it like above.
But as i mentioned, you would need a JS way to Display your data, terms like single page application, MVVM could be worth a lookup there are a lot of usefull libraries like vue, react, knockout, ember ... etc. if you prefer an easy way, they may not be neccessary depending on the complexity of your model.
For your Api you also may dig more into performant serialization, REST, CRUD, authorization and dont repeat yourself. Websockets may also be very interesting.

Comment: Thanks john for your replay , I want to ask you if that work with the bootstrap modal that i create ?

Comment: sure, there is absolutely no reason why it should not.  But further investigation is your part

Comment: This is a good starting point wich helped me a lot. However, if you have a fine input in your form this won't work. I suggest to use [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), it will serialize even form inputs an simplify the ajax form submission. If you want a native method, with modern browsers you can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) to serialize data form inputs with files

Comment: thats true, thanks for pointing that out. My example wont work with files but just wanted to mention that implementing FormData to my example aint difficult, the data property of ajax-call-properties just needs to be formdata like `data = new FormData();` and use `data.append('key','value')` to add parameters