# in 2021 proper methods of ajax posting a form data coming from php

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, forms

I have seen a number of methods dating back to about 2011 in order to take a form and have its data posted via ajax.jquery. I have tried a couple and am just getting the page to reload despite using `preventdefault functions`. From what I have read that tells em something with the jQuery is not right but I am uncertain as to what. I am trying to take data from my form, have the jQuery listen for the form submit by targeting the actual form id and then call a PHP function in order to have that data posted to the db. Ultimately nothing happens other than a page reload

the form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="ajax-add-to-form" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" id="FName" name="FName" placeholder="First Name" value="" required>
    <input type="text" id="LName" name="LName" placeholder="Last Name" value="" required>
    <select id="size" required>
        <option value="">Size</option>
        <?php  for($i=1; $i<=15; $i++){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="MobileNumber" name="MobileNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" value="" required>
    <input type="email" id="Customer_Email" name="Customer_Email" placeholder="Email Address" value="" required>
    <input type="submit"  name="ajax-add-to-form" value="Add to">
</form>
the jquery

        jQuery('document').ready( function(){
            jQuery('#ajax-add-to-form').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
                        jQuery('#jx-loading').show();
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                                        type: 'post',
                                                        url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
                                                        data: { 
                                                        action: 'ajax-php-function'},
                                                        success: function(data)
                                {jQuery('#jx-loading').hide();}
                                                                            
                                                                })          
                    
    
    }); 
        return false;       
        });
```

the php

```
function ajax-php-function() {          
    global $wpdb;   
    $table = "mytablename";     
    $FName= $_POST['FName'];    
    $LName= $_POST['LName'];    
    $MobileNumber= $_POST['MobileNumber'];  
    $Email = $_POST['Email '];          
    $data = array(
    'FName' => $FName,
    'LName' => $LName,      
    'MobileNumber' => $MobileNumber,        
    'Email' => $Email);     
    $success = $wpdb->insert( $table, $data );          
    if($success)
    {echo json_encode($last_data);} 
    else{       echo 'error';   }   die;            
}
```

Comment: It's best to put preventDefault() as the first line of the submit function. Other than that...do you have any errors in the browser's Console? Your details are little bit vague, to say the least

Comment: P.s. if you don't want to use jQuery, you can use fetch() instead, which doesn't require any external libraries. It's built into all browsers in the last few years (apart from IE11)

Comment: P.s. do you realise you aren't actually submitting any data with the Ajax request? You submit the action name, but no form data. Look into jQuery's serialize() function

Comment: you can take a look at the js-part of my answer to get an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087779/submit-symfony-3-form-with-ajax/44088132#44088132

Comment: @adyson no errors but who knows since the page refreshes. I do know that I am not submitting the data via Ajax, which is what the PHP action is for, at least as I understand it. . I certainly dont want to serialize the data but need it in its individual columns. I did move the `preventdefault` to the very top and no change.

Comment: `do know that I am not submitting the data via Ajax, which is what the PHP portion is for. `....this statement appears to make no sense. Do you understand that PHP can't process any form data unless you send it some?

Comment: Perhaps I am not doing something right? My understanding is that the jquery/ajax is looking for the submit. On submit it is executing the `data`: `action` `ajax-php-function` which is what is posting the actual data to the db, no? Am I missing something in my understanding of how this works?

Comment: `On submit it is executing the data: action ajax-php-function which is what is posting the actual data to the db` ...a) it posts data to the _PHP script_. The PHP script communicates with the database. b) it only sends what you tell it to. At the moment you're telling it to send `action: 'ajax-php-function'`. So the only thing sent to PHP is a parameter named "action". Nothing from your form is sent to PHP. Also I don't see anything in your PHP code which would actually execute the PHP function. Sure you visit the URL, but what actually triggers the function? Is there more PHP in that script?

Comment: (Some background, perhaps: If you use a HTML form, but don't use AJAX, then when you submit the form, the browser automatically collects all data from the form and sends it to the server in a HTTP request, where PHP can read it. The disadvantage here is that it causes the whole page to be refreshed. With AJAX, you take control of the HTTP request. You lose the problem of the whole page refreshing, but you gain a new one - sending the form data is no longer automatic, you have to make sure you write code in such a way that it includes the necessary data in the request.)

Comment: Thanks. Maybe then my understanding is not what I think it is, or so it seems. I thought the function was triggered or accessed in the action of the ajax? Sine that doesn't seem to be the case, what is the solution in order to make this work the way I want since I don't think I understand this set up like I thought? :/ IE how should I be passing the data and calling that function if its not in the way I wrote?

Comment: Ajax makes a http request to a URL. It cannot run a specific function. It does not know that the server can run PHP. It just sends the request and waits for a response. If the URL you send the request to is a .PHP file then the server will execute the PHP code within it (and the response which goes back to the Ajax code will contain whatever the PHP code outputs). In PHP, you can declare a function like you have done. But the function doesn't actually run unless you write a line of code to call it

Comment: P.s. one question...is your PHP application a wordpress site? Because there might be slightly different rules if you're doing it within a wordpress context - it has a framework which you might be able to take advantage of for doing ajax calls. I expect it's documented online. I only ask this because of the $wpdb reference in your PHP code.

Comment: Sure is a WP site. I know that (without a form) this concept works for other ajax requests since that is the way I have been doing that for other functions and scripts. Outside of the WP concept, what is the proper way to do this? How do I pass the data or grab the form data in the AJAX concept?

Comment: Normally you'd use jQuery serialize() to capture the form data and send the result of that to the server. Then PHP could read it. And you'd make an explicit call to the PHP function in the PHP script

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but serializing serializes it in the db?

Comment: No. Nothing to do with the db. It happens client side in the browser. It serialised the form field data into URL-encoded format suitable for including in the body of a http request, or on the query string. Basically puts the data into the same as the browser would do automatically if you submitted the form without Ajax. The result of that jQuery function is a string which you can then set as the `data` option in the $.ajax call. The data is then sent to the server in a format which PHP can read, and PHP puts it into the $_POST array ready to process further (such as saving to dB, if required)

Comment: You need to remove from your mind the notion that the browser or JavaScript code can somehow talk directly to the database. The communication chain for submitting a form via Ajax is as follows: user enters data into html form in browser, and clicks submit. JavaScript (running in the html page currently loaded in the browser) detects the submit event and intercepts it. JavaScript generates http request via Ajax and sends data to server. Webserver receives request. If URL ends in .PHP then it forwards the request to PHP. PHP executes the script file, reads the data...

Comment: ...included in the request into the $_POST variables. PHP code then runs which takes those variables and processes them in some way - usually, but not always, saving the data into a database table. PHP then outputs a response (e.g. indicating success or failure). Webserver returns the response inside a http response. Ajax/JavaScript code detects the end of the request and the receives response. JavaScript can then process the response (e.g. to provide on screen feedback, move to next step in the UI, or whatever). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Because this utilized Wordpress, Ultimately the form and its old handler were being trashed by some other element in the website. Could have been WP or one of the few plug ins I could not remove as it is the page builder (Elementor, Elementor Essentials). After disabling all the other plug ins it is narrowed down to that. The code solution was:
....

```
jQuery(document).on('submit', '#ajax-add-to-waitlist-form', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
```

.......

Instead of

```
jQuery('#ajax-add-to-form').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
```